# Is it possible to make this JavaScript on a page run to add content to the page - using wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: javascript, php, wkhtmltopdf

I’m using wkhtmltopdf to try to get a pdf of a page. However, when I run it for one particular page I get a pdf with the heading but nothing else. When I emulate print, or disable javascript on that page (https://www.princess.com/legal/passage_contract/), it’s the same, it just displays the heading of the page and no other content.

I have these options set, and they work for all the other pages I'm making pdfs of:

```
     $knpSnappyPdf->setOption('enable-javascript', true);
     $knpSnappyPdf->setOption('javascript-delay', 5000);
     $knpSnappyPdf->setOption( 'load-error-handling', 'ignore');
```

I think the problem is this function (screenshot below) on the page that’s not running. On the page itself, when JavaScript isn't disabled, it replaces that comment `<!---- To be replaced ---->` with mark up and you can see the content on the page.

[screenshot of markup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Srq0A.png)

When I run the wkhtmltopdf command with `--debug-javascript` and I get this error:

```
TypeError: p13n_list_item_241242.run is not a function. (In 'p13n_list_item_241242.run()', 'p13n_list_item_241242.run' is undefined)
```

I’m just not sure how to get this to run with wkhtmltopdf/if it's possible. Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions? Thanks

Comment: what is p13n_list_item_241242? since your not getting $ or P13NListItem is undefined, js is working, without seeing how you load the js or what P13NListItem is, its hard to tell

Comment: @Yogi I've added the link to the page I'm try to convert. Does that help?